# How to fix 'access denied in integration test with jest and travis-ci build process'

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs, travis-ci

I am trying my HTTP client package and I want to build it in Travis-ci. I have an integration test with jest that it will run a simple nodejs server for testing my package. It runs locally but in Travis I see

> listen EACCES: permission denied 0.0.0.0:80:80

I think the problem is something with running test server on Travis environment

My [project link](https://github.com/miladbonakdar/CRUDly)

here is my .travis.yml

```
language: node_js
node_js:
  - node
notifications:
  email:
    recipients:
      - miladbonak@gmail.com
    on_success: never
    on_failure: always
```

Comment: Did you import the project from GitHub to Travis?
Did you allow Travis to access your GitHub?

Comment: Yes, I did. the error I got is in the middle of the building process and unit tests are all passed